# table cell border change on hover

Tags: html, css, wicket

I am doing a webapp and I have a table which is generated by wicket ListView.
What the app does is that when the mouse hovers over a cell, the app will populate an info panel via ajax and what I want is to change cell border so that the user can know which cell the information is related to.
currently I have the following code in css. (scroll-content-item is the class of the table)

```
scroll-content-item td:hover{
border-style:outset;
border-width:5px;
border-color:#0000ff;}
```

This does give the border on hover but as soon as the user move the mouse outside the cell the border is gone. What I want is a way to make the border stay as long as the mouse doesn't move to another cell. Is there any way to make the border stay until the mouse is moved onto another cell? I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: As soon as the user move the mouse outside the cell the border is gone. What I want is a way to make the border stay as long as the mouse doesn't move to another cell.                                                 I don't understand what you want.

Comment: @LT_Chen this can be done using JavaScript but not with plain css :(

Comment: say a have a table row <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>, what I want is when mouse is moved on 1, a border is added to one. you can move the mouse away to anywhere else on the page except for 2 and the border stays there. when mouse is on 2, the border on 1 disappears and a border is added to 2

Comment: @ShivKumarGanesh can you give me some help on that?

Comment: @LT_Chen Already someone has put up a demo :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't do it with CSS. You can use JS though. Here's an example using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

```
$("td").hover(function() {
    $("td").removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4nMwg/)

Comment: isn't this the same as using `td:hover {border: 1px solid #ccc;}`

Comment: No. `:hover` will remove the effect on mouse out. This will remove the effect when you hover over something else.

Comment: isn't that what op wanted? isn't that what your example does?

Comment: oh I think I get the idea. So first its removing the class for all td element and then add the class to the current td. Thanks I'll give it a shot.

Comment: OP wanted what my example does. Not what CSS alone can do. OP wants the effect to stay when you mouseout and only change when you mouseover another td. CSS removes the effect on mouseout

Comment: @LT_Chen make sure you include jQuery in your page.

Comment: @sachleen really appreciate your help, that's a nice demo! I'm still having some problem though..

Answer (score 0):

This is my final solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .highlight{
    border-style:outset;
    border-width:3px;
    border-color:#0000ff;
  }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").hover(function(){
      $("td").removeClass('highlight');
      $(this).addClass('highlight');
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <table class="waypointsTable" border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>some text</td>
        <td>some text</td>
        <td>some text</td>
        <td>some text</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ok I'm just being stupid.. just figured it out by changing $(document).load to $(document).ready

Answer (score 0):

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}

tr td:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

td:hover {
    border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```